# Unable to drag and drop the element using Selenium C# Edge Browser

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, testing, xpath

Following is HTML for source element:

```
<div title="" class="dragItem row " id="DocSelected-1" draggable="true" type="11" data-content="Salary Slips" data-draggable="item" document-required="1" state="notVerified" accountid="0">
                                    <span class="col-xs-10 dl-no-padding">
                                        <span>Salary Slips</span>
                                    </span>
```

and following is HTML for target element:

```
<div class="removeDocs" data-draggable="remove">  Drag here to remove document  </div>
```

Below is the code tried to achieve the drag and drop,

```
IWebElement from = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='DocSelected-1']//span[@class='col-xs-10 dl-no-padding']"));
            IWebElement to = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("removeDocs"));
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            act.DragAndDrop(from, to).Build().Perform();
```

When i tried with the above code, the test case got passed but drag and drop is not done.

So kindly suggest the right way to perform drag and drop operation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below and see if it helps. Locate the elements and then pass them to Drag and Drop. At times, you may need an offset so I added that code also and commented it out.

```
 var ele1 = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='//div[@id='DocSelected-1']"));
 
 var ele2 = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='removeDocs']"));

 DragAndDrop(ele1, ele2);



 public static void DragAndDrop(IWebElement element1, IWebElement element2)
    {
        WaitForElementEnabled(element1);
        WaitForElementEnabled(element2);
        var builder = new Actions(Driver);
        var dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(element1).MoveToElement(element2).Release(element2).Build();
 
     // var dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(element1).MoveToElement(element2, 100, 100).Release(element1).Build();  
        dragAndDrop.Perform();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The test case got passes but drag and drop is not working yet.

Comment: You may have to work with the off-set and adjust the values.